# Defining variables emu8086

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I'm trying to define a byte variable in emu8086 with the initial value of F0H and I receive the following error:

Code:

```
X DB F0H
```

Error:

> (1) zero prefix must be added to a HEX value, for example: 0Ch

what is this error for?

Comment: It literally tells you what to do ... `X DB 0F0h`. That's so that in can be differentiated from a symbol which start with letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the HEX value can be differentiated from a symbols that start with letters.

Answer (score 1):

we need to add 0 before the value of an variable  or we say we attach 0 before value of an variable otherwise it gives an error

Define like this

```
x db 0f0h
```